# What does "he’s only telling it how he sees it" mean? [the question was rewritten]

Tags: meaning

> he’s only *telling* it how he sees it.

Could you please tell me what's the meaning of the sentence above?

> Is there any idiom here?

---

**Note**: The question has rewritten. So the([colleenv](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/9161/colleenv))'s comment refers to the original version of question.

The full text is:

> Beverly listens to him, licks her lips nervously, and waits. No one else
>   volunteers anything.
>   Finally, she blurts out, “There’s something I should probably say.”
>   All eyes turn her way. She almost loses courage. She doesn’t know if the
>   argument between Dana and Matthew is relevant or not, but it will certainly
>   sound damning.
>   “What is it?” David says calmly, as she hesitates.
>   “I heard them arguing, last night.”
>   “Dana and Matthew?” David says, as if in surprise.
>   “Yes.”
>   “What was the argument about, do you know?”
>   She shakes her head. “I heard them shouting, but I couldn’t make out any
>   words. Their room is next to ours, on the same side of the hall.” She looks at
>   her husband. “Henry slept through it all.”
>   “What time was this?”
>   “I don’t know, but late.”
>   “Did it sound . . . violent?” David asks.
>   “I don’t know. It was just raised voices. No crying or anything. Nothing
>   slamming, if that’s what you mean.”
>   There, she’s said it. If Matthew’s done something wrong, then it’s good that
>   she’s told them.
>   David can sense the heightened distress of the others. They don’t like
>   what Beverly has said; it makes them uneasy. They don’t like to think
>   the unthinkable. He can see from their faces that they are all
>   imagining it—the argument, the push down the stairs. He’s sorry for
>   their distress, but **he’s only telling it how he sees it**. It doesn’t
>   seem possible that Dana could have been injured like that from her
>   fall, and he doesn’t want them messing about with the body. And now
>   this new information—Matthew had told him that he and Dana had not
>   argued. If Beverly is to be believed, Matthew lied to him.

Comment: If I said "I'm going to tell you a story...", which definition do you think would apply? (And that's not an answer, because I think "telling it how it is/how you see it" is an idiom that has meaning beyond the meaning of the individual words)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A referee at a football match calls plays **as he sees them**. That is, as he observes and makes judgments and comes to an opinion about the situation.

If you describe a situation in terms that someone else might consider unflattering, and they criticize you for doing so, you might reply:

> Look, I'm only telling it as I see it. I'm not trying to make it out to be any worse or any better than it seems to me.

A person who **tells it as they see it** is not trying to distort the situation as someone might who has a bias or an "agenda". They're trying to be objective as possible, given the limitations of their vantage point.

Comment: There is often a nuance of the teller being blunt or even offensive.

Answer (score 3):

[Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/see?s=t) covers this definition of *see*:

> 5. to perceive things mentally; discern; understand:
>
>    *to see the point of an argument.*

When he's *telling it how he sees it,* he's conveying his thoughts relating to Dana's murder.

There's a common idiom in English that is similar to your sentence (maybe it is being confused in the discussion of idioms) called *[telling it like it is](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tell-it-like-it-is)*, or describing a situation truthfully with no regard for pleasantness to the listener.

In this case, the use of the word *only* implies that David is not intentionally trying to upset the other people; as a detective (I'm guessing), his job is to investigate the scene and find as much information as possible that will solve the case, including a cause (domestic abuse).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an idiom.

The usual idiom in speech is: **to tell it [whatever the thing is] like it is.**

**tell it  how he sees it**, is a variation on that.

The fact it is present progressive refers to a single instance of this in the story. The rest of the paragraph is also in the present tense.

If this were all the time, one would say:

He tells it like it is. [every time he tells the story, for example].

Simple present for verbs like this mean a general statement, not a specific one.